# How to let ubuntu ignore a internal hard-drive when start up?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount, hard-drive, disk

I am dual-booting Ubuntu(12.10) and Windows on different hard drives in my laptop.

For battery life and noise issue, it is possible for me to ignore the Windows drive and prevent it from being mounted?

I tried to look up /etc/fstab but only found the drive for ubuntu...

Is it possible to totally disable the Windows drive on grub(Before the system boots)?
(I use MBR for Windows and choosing system by selecting drive)

Answer (score 1):

you could define an udev rule to unmount the drive after startup, or edit an existing rule in your .rules directory to not even mount it.

Here is some information about udev an the possibilieties you have, and an introduction to rulewriting:
http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

Comment: Thanks for the information!
Sounds there are not trivial solution though...